# QGIS Print Composer Legend: Polygon symbol not closed

Tags: qgis, symbology, print-composer, legend

The legend of my map doesnt't match the symbology of my polygon layer, the polygons are not closed.
Here a screenshot of the layer windows:

[image]

And here one of the legend from the print composer:

[image]

If I increase the size of the outline of the layer symbols >0.5 , it looks like this in the print composer:

[image]

The first three items have increased outline witdh.

How can I avoid this - I need closed squares in the legend, but no thick outline...